# How to override /etc/systemd/system.conf?

Tags: systemd

I want to modify a default behaviour in systemd.
This default behaviour is `CtrlAltDelBurstAction=reboot-force`, commented out in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

I just have to uncomment this line and modify it to `CtrlAltDelBurstAction=none`.
But is there a "clean way" to do it, not interfering with the original distro file?

I tested with `systemctl edit system` but this raise an error stating `system.service` is not found.

Comment: Take a look at *man systemd-system.conf*. You can add a file /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In modern versions of *systemd*, it is possible to override the settings of the "default" config file `/etc/systemd/system.conf` with "specialized" configuration snipplets residing in files under `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/`.

You could place your config line into a file `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/10-suppress-ctraltdel.conf`, then it will be read when you reload the *systemd* configuration (or at next boot). To quote from [the `man systemd-system.conf` page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html):

> The main configuration file is read before any of the configuration directories, and has the lowest precedence; entries in a file in any configuration directory override entries in the single configuration file. Files in the `*.conf.d/` configuration subdirectories are sorted by their filename in lexicographic order, regardless of which of the subdirectories they reside in.

Btw, this kind of configuration override mechanism is now the standard for many Linux services, so the approach discussed here should also work in other situations.

In `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/10-suppress-ctraltdel.conf`,  `CtrlAltDelBurstAction=none` must be in the `[Manager]` section (as noted in the manpage: "All options are configured in the `[Manager]` section"):

```
[Manager]
CtrlAltDelBurstAction=none
```

If a section isn't specified, the option might be ignored, as it might be in the wrong section.

Answer (score 1):

It is a config file, you are allowed to modify it. When you upgrade the `systemd` package most distros will ask you if you want your version or the system maintainer's version.

If you wanted to modify a **service** file, it would be a different matter: they usually reside in `/lib/systemd`, but you can override the original ones by placing your version in `/etc/systemd`.

Comment: "most distros will ask you if you want your version or the system maintainer's version." this is exaclty the essence of my question.