# Remove Suspend / Restart / Power Off… menu from Gnome Shell & GDM

Tags: suspend, gnome-shell, gdm

I need to remove Suspend / Restart / Power Off… menu from Gnome Shell & GDM.
[image]

I’ve been trying using Settings, Gnome Tweaks, Dconf Editor, but nothing found AFAIK.

Trying to enter the Polkit conf file gave the same results.

```
    polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend") {
        return polkit.Result.NO;
    }
});
```

Any clue?

Thank you,
Regards

Comment: same question asked elsewhere - and with some suggestions there: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/remove-suspend-restart-power-off-menu-from-gnome-shell-gdm/12794

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=843568 might be helpful

Comment: Removing them from the menu doesn't prevent them being accessed via another route (e.g. command lne) - you still need the polkit config.

Comment: Hi, I agree, @symcbean, though that is not the point of the question in my reading of it.

Answer (score 0):

**1) For a per user Gnome Shell configuration**, currently, the following well customizable extension seems to do the job well: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/

**2) For the GDM level**, following [Florian Müllner's 2013 bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=843568) response

```
 # cat > /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-site-settings <<EOT
 >[org/gnome/login-screen]
 >disable-restart-buttons=true
 >EOT
 # dconf update
 # systemctl restart gdm.service
```

removes the `Suspend / Restart` part, but also disables `Power Off`.

In sum, create the file `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-site-settings` with the following content

```
 [org/gnome/login-screen]
 disable-restart-buttons=true
```

Then run `dconf update` and subsequently `systemctl restart gdm.service`. Note that the latter command will restart your Gnome session.

Then, following the proposal at the [Gnome Discourse site](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/remove-suspend-restart-power-off-menu-from-gnome-shell-gdm/12794/2?u=ilippert), I like to suggestion to also consider what happens upon the command `ctrl-alt-del`. To implement this, I create the directory  `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/` and in it the file `10-suppress-ctraltdel.conf`, implementing [How to override /etc/systemd/system.conf?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551463/how-to-override-etc-systemd-system-conf) answer, thus entering as content

```
 [Manager]
 CtrlAltDelBurstAction=none
```

Though, instead of `none`, other options are described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/system.conf.d.html#CtrlAltDelBurstAction=).

Comment: Many thanks @ingli for your answer. Do you have any idea if we can do the same but on a per user basis instead of system wide configuration?

Comment: @Nexus1138, please check the edited post and accept if resolved; and vote up if anyhow helpful.

Comment: Thanks @ingli for point 1), this is a customization made as per user, but how would you apply this policy as system wide?

Comment: Dear @Nexus1138, sorry, cannot help with that. I strongly suggest you ask a new question on that, and refer to this one. I believe the question you originally asked is sufficiently answered. If your question was not precisely worded, then please ask a new question, building on this one. I am sad you don't provide recognition of my work to help you.

Comment: I provided recognition to your work by thanks, but can't vote on this as the question is not answered. Thanks again for your time @ingli.